# C# Xamarin How to develop a custome keyboard?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, keyboard, gesture

I'm thinking to develop a custom keyboard in C#-xamarin.
But there's no documentation for this.
The documentation is only available for java.
So, I want to know that can somebody please guide me that how to develop custom keyboard in C# xamarin?
also, is it possible to detect swipe up/down/right/left gestures on every key?
Seeking for the help.

Comment: I personally think that nobody should try creating anything that is not expected to be cross-platform using Xamarin. You know, it is like developing new virtual machine Engine using JavaScript - it is possible in general, but completely not designed for this. You will just deliver a lot of pain to yourself in progress of development, and to your keyboard's users in case you succeed.

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko, Can't we develop general apps with xamarin? I think that it is recommended by xamarin people? please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't say that you are wrong, but I have my opinion and experience. I am a Java Android developer, but have to support Xamarin project also. So there are few reasons why Android-only apps should not be developed in Xamarin. 1) the app size will be significantly higher. It will include some additional libraries to run your compiled code on Android in any case. 2) you will have problems compiling your project for different Android CPU architectures (x86, arm-v7, arm-v8,arm-v8_64, etc). So you'll have to solve much more problems. 3) Your app will work slower then native java app.

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko bro, You are right, actually I also want to use java+android studio, but I'm fond of intelisense which visual studio provides. today, I'll download android studio, and will try it, I also feel that the android apps should be developed in java only, because, in xamarin, there's no proper documentation for advance things either. also, can you help me regarding the swipe gestures for the keyboard keys?

Comment: @VladMatvienko `slower then native java app` :  You should look at the independent benchmarks, Xamarin actually tends to match and/or beat Java in most areas of app performance...  You are right about the `.apk` size but not sure why building for different ABIs would be a problem.

Comment: @SushiHangover are you developing in xamarin.android?

Comment: @AkashKakkar `Xamarin.Android` and `Xamarin.iOS`. Some `Xamarin.Forms` but mainly stick to native UIs due to performance/memory/bugs in `Xamarin.Forms` (Forms is getting better and the current roadmap is stressing quality and performance over features which is a good thing...)

Comment: @SushiHangover so, did you had any problem in starting? like, no proper documentation is available for xamarin.android. also, the community is very small, and examples are also not available, how did you manage then? because, I'm also having a lot of problem while developing in xamarin.android. Seems that I'll have to switch to java/android studio, but I like C# and intelisense. what to do?

Comment: @AkashKakkar That is a personal choice you will have to make. Yes the Xamarin community is smaller as the initial release of Android was in 2008 and Xamarin 2.0 was released in 2013, it is very active and growing due to the Microsoft acquisition. As far as documentation, I have never been road blocked due to documentation, `Xamarin.Android` wraps the complete Java API with C#, so you can always review the Android Java docs...

Comment: @SushiHangover ok, but aren't there any syntax/structural differences bitween java implementation and c#/xamarin implementation? can we easily apply java examples on xamarin.android?  please help me.

Comment: @AkashKakkar https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/porting_java_to_csharp/

Comment: @SushiHangover OK, i've checked it, but, my question was, that is this possible to easily apply the java examples on xamarin.android? (by porting the language specific things offcourse). also, can we create fully featured keyboard in xamarin.android? will it be easy in java or xamarin and java both will be same?

Comment: I'm sorry for my worst explaining skills

Comment: @AkashKakkar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31266845/xamarin-custom-keyboard and https://github.com/Vaikesh/CustomKeyboard .....

Comment: Hi bro, I've checked both of the resources and now I've got some understanding. but still I'm unable to know that how to detect swipe gestures for individual keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only tried to make my phone into a custom tablet for my PC before(not using C# and xamarin) so I may not be effective in helping you but I found one source-code that may help/interest you : https://github.com/Vaikesh/CustomKeyboard

And yes, it is possible to detect swipe up/down/right/left gestures on every key provided that the keys are large enough. (Don't expect every tiny key to correctly/accurately detect swipe-directions)

And like what @Vlad Matvienko commented, I don't think you should be trying it. But if its for personal use or just for fun, then go ahead.

Comment: Thanks bro for your help, I'll check this resource. also, I'm developing this keyboard for my personal use, also, can you please guide me that how to detect swipe gesture for the keys? (I'll be using only 8-9 keys on the keyboard so, the size will be big enough)

Comment: I recommend you learn how to make your program detect swipe-gestures on your android first(google around for tutorials that best fits to teach you). Afterwards, you can just make 1 button as a test and figure it out around with yourself. Mostly its simple after you learn how to make your program detects swipe gestures, cause whats left after you learn it is just simply making the size/area of where it will detect. (Somehow like making a canvas in CSS/HTML) [Sorry for my bad english, I am bad at explaining]

Comment: no problem bro, I'm also bad in explaining. I've learned that how to detect swipe gestures. I've also praticaled on buttons textviews etc, and I'm successful, but in the keyboard, there're no buttons etc, the keys are a different view I think. so, for that view, I'm unable to know that how to implement ontouch and onfling methods. :(