# How to disable the text editing feature of keyboard in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, keyboard

I want to **disable the text editing feature** of the **keyboard** which allows the keyboard to **copy paste the values in Entry**. This is my renderer code.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    if (Control != null)
    {                  
        Control.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText; 
                  
        Control.CustomSelectionActionModeCallback = new Callback();
        Control.CustomInsertionActionModeCallback = new Callback();
        Console.WriteLine("CustomSelectionActionModeCallback");
                  
        Control.SetTextIsSelectable(false);
        Control.LongClickable = false;
        Control.SetOnTouchListener(EntryTouchListener.Instance.Value);
    }
}
```

This is the **MyEntry class** code

```
public class MyEntry : Entry
{
    public MyEntry()
    {
        BackgroundColor = Color.Gray;
        Keyboard = Keyboard.Create(KeyboardFlags.None);
    }
}
```

I have tried to set the **KeyboardFlags as none** as suggested in the following suggestion

[Can I prevent keyboard suggestions from Xamarin.forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338767/can-i-prevent-keyboard-suggestions-from-xamarin-forms)

Still it didn't help. This is how my **UI** looks like

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have to **hide or disable the text editing** feature from my keyboard. I have no clue how to fix this issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately, the built-in keyboard seems to lack that degree of control. Also, a phone vendor, or the user could install a *different* default keyboard. Bottom line: you can't allow a default Keyboard to appear, if you need control over what it can do. To avoid this, make a [Custom Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31266845/199364)..